# Flink Confluent Avro Deserialized data cannot be read into logstash

Tags: logstash, apache-flink, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have a Flink sink written using ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema

```
    return new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(
            topicConfig.name(),
            ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema
                    .forSpecific(MyPojo.class, topicConfig.schemaRegistryUrl()),
            topicConfig.forConsumer()
```

I dont have a schema defined so when it serialzes my output it writes this to kafka output topic with a schema like below:

[image]

Now I am reading the output topic using the below schema into logstash using the logstash avro codec plugin: https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry

This however fails with an error:

```
[2021-07-22T22:00:07,638][FATAL][logstash.runner ] An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#<Avro::SchemaParseError: record is a reserved type name.>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.10.0/lib/avro/schema.rb:575:in `add_name'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.10.0/lib/avro/schema.rb:253:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.10.0/lib/avro/schema.rb:325:in `initialize'",
```

Here is my logstash conf file:

```
topics => ["my-flink-output-topic-name"]
codec => avro_schema_registry {
    endpoint => "http://schema-registry:8085"
}
```

This is because of the name:record field in the output format is thrown here: https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/ruby/lib/avro/schema.rb#L634.

Is there a way I can specify what the name should be instead of default of "record" to the Flink output writer? Any other options to deserialize avro messages using a schema registry into logstash?

Comment: A _consumer_ doesn't register a schema in the registry. A producer does. That being said, you should try registering a schema beforehand if you want control of the name of it

Comment: I tried that. I precreated a schema with the same subject name with the name:record changed to name:something_else. However the flink consumer seems to be overwriting the one created with a new version with name:record.

Comment: AFAIK, the registry should reject that because changing the record name isn't backwards compatible